# Adding items to spinner dynamically in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I've followed some threads here on SO but I can't get this to work even though I feel like it's matching the examples and I don't know why.

I created a simple spinner.. and in my AsyncTaskRunner class I pull information from a REST API and then in the onPostExecute I try to add it to the Spinner.. but when I debug/run my app the Spinner contents is empty.  When debugging the webChannelList is for sure not empty and has content

If I don't try to add anything dynamically and just add things manually in the onCreate method it works just fine.. but for realistic purposes I'm trying to do it dynamically.

SO was saying to pass in the MainActivity which i did.. but it's not working.  Help!

**SOLUTION:** I had `Debug.waitForDebugger();` in my doInBackground function... once I removed that it worked perfectly.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/singularSpinner" />
```

I ommited stuff not relevant to what i'm asking

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  // Global Variables
  private List<String> webChannelList = new ArrayList<String>();
  private Spinner spinner;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Load Singular Web Channels into GUI
      AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner(this);
      runner.execute();
  }

  class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      MainActivity mainActivity;

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Debug.waitForDebugger();  //REMOVING THIS WORKS            
        webChannelList = StuffFromAPI();
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (!webChannelList.isEmpty()) {
          spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.singularSpinner);

          // Creating adapter for spinner
          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, webChannelList);

          // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
          dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

          // Attaching data adapter to spinner
          spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**  so I ommited the StuffFromAPI() function and just added stuff manually with webChannelList.add("hello"); for example and it ran perfectly from the StuffFromAPI() function .. strangely even though I just commented it out and added things in manually.  Almost like it's caching?  But now I can't replicate it.. so something is going on and i dont know what.  I'm new to Android development maybe there's something very obvious that I'm missing.  All I do is go to Build --> Run or Build --> Debug and i have a tablet attached

**EDIT 2:** is it possible that the onPostExecute function runs BEFORE it grabs the items from my API?  which still doesn't make sense because I physically see the content in there when i debug but it still doesn't show in the GUI

Comment: did you check that you getting list of string from `StuffFromAPI()` method?

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati yes that's the first thing I checked.  I put a breakpoint in there and I clearly see the String content I'm trying to add.  Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

Response to **Edit2**:  Yes it is possible, it all depends on if your API calls are asynchronous.  You should check the size of the array list that is returned.  How are you fetching the data?

This is not your problem, but I'd suggest arranging your code a bit differently.

Create members for the ArrayAdapter and the response data list, webChannelList.  Then in the onPostExecute, all you should need to do is call notify that the data has changed.  This is a bit more flexible and easier to maintain down the road.

```
ArrayList<someType> webChannelList = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.singularSpinner);

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, webChannelList);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // Attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            // Load Singular Web Channels into GUI
            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner(this);
            runner.execute();
        }

        class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            MainActivity mainActivity;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                webChannelList = StuffFromAPI();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  i had a check "if (!webChannelList.isEmpty()) {" in the onPostExecute that I didn't put in the OP.. so it wouldn't make sense i'm just making the call in the doInBackground function very simply.

once i figure out why this isn't working i will definitely look into your structure reccommendations.  thank you

Comment: i'm looking at your suggestion now.. are you missing declaring the dataAdapter as a global variable?

Comment: Yes, add that as a class member.

Comment: I just noticed this, but why is MainActivity declared in the AsyncTask?

Comment: I'm new to Android..  i didn't know how to pass it in otherwise.  I was just trying to store the MainActivity into a variable so i can use it within AsyncTask.  if you could show me the proper way that would be cool.